# Verificar si un string contiene un espacio

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un register sencillo en React y para validar el formulario necesito que el campo `name` **no contenga espacios**, cuál es la mejor manera de verificar esto en JavaScript?

Dicen que con `.trim()`se puede hacer pero no encuentro algo que me sirva

Comment: Trim elimina los espacios al principio y al final-> "  hola " quedaría "hola", pero "h ola" seguiría siendo "h ola". Necesitas usar `indexOf(" ")` para determinar si hay algún espacio. Por cierto, decir "No encuentro algo que me sirva" da muy mala imagen... parece que lo único que te interese sea copiar y pegar algo que ya funcione... eres programador, ***HAZ*** algo que te sirva, no lo intentes *encontrar*.

Comment: @Benito-B Si lees bien y tienes capacidad notoria de lectura crítica puedes darte cuenta fácilmente que la expresión que dije denota que ya he buscado e intentado; igualmente por algo coloqué "dicen" eso que indica?...  En fin, nunca hables sin ver el contexto que tienen palabras ni su significado, eso no hace al programador ni a su búsqueda por hallar una solución (tampoco somos perfectos, por algo existe esta comunidad). Igualmente gracias tu respuesta da el resultado correcto, saludos.

Comment: Si pones "Dicen que con .trim()se puede hacer pero no encuentro algo que me sirva" entonces parece que no intentaste nada, ni siquiera el trim. Entonces tu pregunta parece simplemente como que no intentaste nada... te recomendaria mirar el [tour] y tambien [ask]

Comment: @gbianchi creo que deberias cerrar la pregunta ya van 3 respuestas y contando

Comment: Pero una de las respuestas, es correcta...

Comment: @Dan Me temo que si tengo capacidad de lectura. La suficiente para leer la documentación de javascript al menos. Me pregunto si tú tienes dicha capacidad y has decidido usarla con las reglas de SO antes de abrir una pregunta (tal como se indica que debes hacer en la pantalla que se te muestra al escribir la primera pregunta), puesto que en esas reglas se especifica que una pregunta ***debe incluir el código de lo que se ha intentado***. Dime, dónde lo has incluido? Porque me temo que *dicen que...*, **NO** es un [mre] válido. *Dicen* que las reglas están para leerlas, y entenderlas :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para saber si el string contiene espacios sin orden particular, creo que deberías usar [`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

```js
const str = " abc   ";
const sinOrdenEspecifico = str.includes(" ");
console.log(sinOrdenEspecifico);
```

Comment: Hay un comentario que dice de usar indexof.. esa no es la mejor forma?

Comment: @gbianchi Sería una opción también usar `str.indexOf(" ")`, método el cual devolvería `-1` en caso de que no tenga espacios, tanto `includes` como `indexOf` son métodos válidos

Comment: Igual yo cambiaria la parte que dice la forma mas sencilla es una expresion regular.. en realidad la forma mas sencilla es includes, que va dentro de un if y devuelve true o false... lo otro, es mas complicado e implica una expresion regular.. que para colmo no busca espacios en el medio... que es lo que la pregunta pide...

Comment: @anythingg, el mismo usuario dice que necesita que el name no contenga espacios, así que el como tal lo que busca al final es eliminar los espacios